# What to write in this contract

Tags: uml, ooad, contracts

I'm designing a academic decision support system. I have to write documentation for that project. The part I am stuck on is writing contracts.

I've a use case **Generate custom reports**.

The interaction the user will do with the system is `setParametersforReport()`.

In this function he will set attributes, like `student_rollNumber` or `marks`, or `warning count` or anything else he wants to see on the report.

However I am confused what to write in the **contract's post condition**.

The 3 things that I should mention are:

1. Instances created
2. Associations formed or broken
3. Attributes changed

I don't get what to write in that and how to explain since nothing is actually being created. I have all the data I want in the database and I am accessing them without classes. I am confused because database instance can't be created.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Postconditions are used to specify the state of the system at the end of the operation execution. In your case it looks like the state at the system at the end is the same that the state at the beginning since you´re not modifying the database (and you´re not storing the report instance either). Therefore I don't see the point of defining a contract for this operation.